# What is the difference between normal and lambda Haskell functions?

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I'm a beginner to Haskell and I've been following the e-book [Get Programming with Haskell](https://www.manning.com/books/get-programming-with-haskell)

I'm learning about closures with Lambda functions but I fail to see the difference in the following code:

```
genIfEven :: Integral p => p -> (p -> p) -> p
genIfEven x = (\f -> isEven f x)

genIfEven2 :: Integral p => (p -> p) -> p -> p
genIfEven2 f x = isEven f x
```

It would be great if anyone could explain what the precise difference here is

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what sort of answer you're expecting. Those are two different functions which need to be used in different ways. They're not interchangeable.

Comment: Well... the arguments come in a different order? But that has nothing to do with whether it is a lambda or a "normal" Haskell function. What is the stimulus that caused you to try to find a difference between these? Except for the monomorphism restriction there isn't really a difference in meaning between the two syntaxes.

Comment: I am rather curious what `isEven` does.

Comment: @dfeuer I predict that it does the same thing as `genIfEven2`, har har.

Comment: Lambda expressions are perfectly normal functions. There are some differences in typing between lambda expressions and top-level or `let`-bound functions, mostly relating to the advanced `RankNTypes` language extension, but you shouldn't be worrying about that. GHC also uses lambda expressions in certain contexts to guess at intended function "arity" for optimization purposes, but you shouldn't worry about that right now either.

Comment: Your example is confusing as there are _more_ differences than just "normal" vs. lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a basic level<sup>1</sup>, there isn't really a difference between "normal" functions and ones created with lambda syntax. What made you think there was a difference to ask what it is? (In the particular example you've shown, the functions take their parameters in a different order, but are otherwise the same; either of them could be defined with lambda syntax or "normal" syntax)

Functions are first class values in Haskell. Which means you can pass them to other functions, return them as results, store and retrieve them in data structures, etc, etc. Just like you can with numbers, or strings, or any other value.

Just like with numbers, strings, etc, it's helpful to have syntax for denoting a function value, because you might want to make a simple one right in the middle of other code. It would be pretty horrible if you, say, needed to pass `x + 1` to some function and you couldn't just write the literal `1` for the number one, you had to instead go elsewhere in the file and add a `one = 1` binding so that you could come back and write `x + one`. In exactly the same way, you might need to pass to some other function a function for adding 1; it would be annoying to go elsewhere in the file and add a separate definition `plusOne x = x + 1`, so lambda syntax gives us a way of writing "function literals": `\x -> x + 1`.<sup>2</sup>

Considering "normal" function definition syntax, like this:

```
incrementAllBy _ [] = []
incrementAllBy n (x:xs) = (x + n) : xs
```

Here we don't have any bit of source code that just represents the function value that `incrementAllBy` is a name for. The function is *implied* in this syntax, spread over (possibly) multiple "rules" that say what value our function *returns* given that it is applied to arguments of a certain form. This syntax also fundamentally forces us to bind the function to a name. All of that is in contrast to lambda syntax which just directly represents the function itself, with no bundled case analysis or name.

However they are both merely different ways of writing down functions. Once defined, there is no difference between the functions, whichever syntax you used to express them.

---

You mentioned that you were learning about closures. It's not really clear how that relates to the question, but I can guess it's being a bit confusing.

I'm going to say something slightly controversial here: you don't need to learn about closures.<sup>3</sup>

A closure is what is involved in making something like `incrementAllBy n xs = map (\x -> x + n) xs` work. The function created here `\x -> x + n` depends on `n`, which is a parameter so it can be different every time `incrementAllBy` is called, and there can be multiple such calls running at the same time. So this `\x -> x + n` function can't end up as just a chunk of compiled code at a particular address in the program's binary, the way top-level functions are. The structure in memory that is passed to `map` has to either store a copy of `n` or store a reference to it. Such a structure is called a "closure", and is said to have "closed over" `n`, or "captured" it.

In Haskell, you don't need to know any of that. I view the expression `\n -> x + n` as simply creating a new function value, depending on the value `n` (and also the value `+`, which is a first-class value too!) that happens to be in scope. I don't think you need to think about this any differently than you would think about the expression `x + n` creating a new numeric value depending on a local `n`. Closures in Haskell only matter when you're trying to understand how the language is implemented, not when you're programming in Haskell.

Closures **do** matter in imperative languages. There the question of whether (the equivalent of) `\x -> x + n` stores a reference to `n` or a copy of `n` (and when the copy is taken, and how deeply) is critical to understanding how code using this function works, because `n` isn't just a way of referring to a value, it's a variable that has (potentially) different values over time.

But in Haskell I don't really think we should teach beginners about the term or concept of closures. It vastly over-complicates "you can make new functions out of existing values, even ones that are only locally in scope".

So if you have been given these two functions as examples to try and illustrate the concept of closures, and it isn't making sense to you what difference this "closure" makes, you can probably ignore the whole issue and move on to something more important.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sometimes which choice of "equivalent" syntax you use to write your code *does* affect operational behaviour, like performance. Usually (but not always) the effect is negligible. As a beginner, I highly recommend ignoring such issues for now, so I haven't mentioned them. It's much easier to learn the principles involved in reasoning about how your code might be executed once you've got a thorough understanding of what all the language elements are supposed to mean.

It can sometimes also affect the way GHC infers types (mostly not actually the fact that they're lambdas, but if you bind function names without syntactic parameters as in `plusOne = \x -> x + 1` you can trip up the monomorphism restriction, but that's another topic covered in many Stack Overflow questions, so I won't address it here).

<sup>2</sup> In this case you could also use an operator section to write an even simpler function literal as `(+1)`.

<sup>3</sup> Now I'm going to teach you about closures so I can explain why you don't need to know about closures. :P

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference whatsoever, except one: lambda expressions  don't need a name. For that reason, they are sometimes called "anonymous functions" in other languages.

If you plan to use a function often, you'll want to give it a name, if you only need it once, a lambda will usually do, as you can define it at the site where you use it.

You can, of course, name an anonymous function *after* it is born:

```
genIfEven2 = \f x -> isEven f x
```

That would be *completely* equivalent to your definition.